# Extra user at Users Account

Tags: 14.04, username, user-management

I have installed this operating system my self and created one account as an owner and root.

I do not know where " Me " account came from. However, I get many access permissions error, even-while, working as the root account. As you may see at the PrtScr picture "Owner Me" account does not have an option to select someone else and only one account exists at system sittings.

gtk nautilus and sudo stopped working, su does not accept my known administrator password. Ubuntu 14.04 3.13.0-24 generic #47.

Any help around these malfunctions?

[image]

Comment: When you type umask on the terminal what does it say? also type id and give me the output of that

Answer (score 0):

'Me' is actually you the owner of the file. Its not a separate account.

Coming to 'su' you should type

> sudo su

in terminal(ctrl+Alt+T) not just 'su'